# Google distance matrix api no longer support several origins?

Tags: json, google-distancematrix-api

Today I woke up and want to run my code (which was working fine) but I got several errors - Undefined offset errors while looping through the json response obtained after a request containing several origins and destinations has been sent:

```
$request = file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=$OriginUrl&destinations=$DestinationUrl&mode=driving");
$resultdistance = json_decode($request, true);

for($i=0;$i<count($LocationDetails);$i++){

        $distanceM = $resultdistance['rows'][$i]['elements'][$i]['distance']['value'];
        $distanceKM = $distanceM / 1000;
        $TravelDistance = round($distanceKM,1); // Distance from Act 1 and Act 2
        $DistanceText = $resultdistance['rows'][$i]['elements'][$i]['distance']['text'];
        $TimeToTravelSec =  $resultdistance['rows'][$i]['elements'][$i]['duration']['value'];
        $TimeToTravelText = $resultdistance['rows'][$i]['elements'][$i]['duration']['text'];

}
```

I then enter the http request manually in the address bar with several origins and notice that the request has been sent with only one origin:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Hilton+Mauritius+Resort+&+Spa,+Coastal+Road,+Flic+en+Flac,+Mauritius|LAventure+du+Sucre,+B18,+Pamplemousses,+Mauritius&destinations=Cascavelle,+Riviere+Noire+District|Mauritius+Aquarium,+B38,+Camp+Bestel,+Pamplemousses+District,+Mauritius|Blue+Safari+Submarines,+B36,+Trou-aux-Biches,+Mauritius|&mode=driving

[image: valid HTML]

Two origins has been sent:
1. Hilton+Mauritius+Resort+&+Spa,+Coastal+Road,+Flic+en+Flac,+Mauritius
2.LAventure+du+Sucre,+B18,+Pamplemousses,+Mauritius

but only the first one has been taken into consideration (see image above or click on the link to send request and see the result) ! A few days ago I was using about 5 origins and it was working Please Help !

Comment: I kinda find this strange cuz I just interchanged the origins and it seems to work fine. I am not sure of what to issue and couldn't find anything in the documentation as well. Try to report a bug to Google about this

Comment: I am sorry,I forgot to write that I found a solution, I also interchanged the origins and found that it work fine. Then I spent more than 1 hour to find that the '&' in the : Hilton+Mauritius+Resort+&+Spa,+Coastal+Road,+Flic+en+Flac,+Mauritius was causing this bug I remove the & and it work fine. There should be no & in the url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remove the '&' in :

```
Hilton+Mauritius+Resort+&+Spa,+Coastal+Road,+Flic+en+Flac,+Mauritius
```

and it works fine.There should not be any '& in the origin's name and destination's names because the parameters are already using the '&' sign and this might cause some problems.

Comment: Good to know that. But still the interchanged of origins contain `&` and it seems to work perfect

Comment: Can you update the answer cuz someone might be misguided by your last line. There will be `&` in your request URL as your sending those parameters i.e., origins and destinations

Comment: Yes, it works when you interchanged the order of the origins name and I don't know how. But it will be preferable not to use the & in the origins and destinations.